# Laravel 5.6 regex validation always showing error

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am trying to validate entered string against regex expression, this working fine on websites like [regexr](https://regexr.com/4333n) and [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KClpvB/1) but it is always showing error on in laravel.

Regex should match with following strings:

```
FL-IV-1234
FL-III-1234
FL-II-56789
FL-I-1234334
FL-BR-II-53440
fl-iv-8484
fl-iii-84894
fl-ii-94 
fl-i-334
```

Expression:

`/(fl)-(IV-|I{1,3}-)(\d*\W)|((fl)-(br)-II-\d*\W)/i`

Code:

```
$pattern = '/(fl)-(IV-|I{1,3}-)(\d*\W)|((fl)-(br)-II-\d*\W)/i';
$request->validate([
        'lic_no' => array('required', 'regex:'.$pattern),
    ]);
```

Also tried without variable:

```
$request->validate([
        'lic_no' => array('required', 'regex:/(fl)-(IV-|I{1,3}-)(\d*\W)|((fl)-(br)-II-\d*\W)/'),
    ]);
```

Error message:

`The lic no format is invalid.`

Please suggest, Thanks!

Comment: BTW, it seems you may use `/^fl-(IV|I{1,3}|br-II)-\d*\W?$/i`. The second alternative is almost identical to the first one, and the last `\W` prevents the last item to match. See https://regex101.com/r/34eka2/1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for improved expression, but still same error message `The lic no format is invalid`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `/^fl-(IV|I{1,3}|br-II)-\d*\W?$/i` this one worked, can you please add answer so that I can accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not match the last item in your list of expected matches. You may combine the second alternative with the first one and make the last `\W` optional:

```
/^fl-(IV|I{1,3}|br-II)-\d*\W?$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/34eka2/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `fl-` - a `fl_` text
- `(IV|I{1,3}|br-II)` - a capturing group (add `?:` after `(` to make it non-capturing) matching `IV`, one to three `I`s or `br-II`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `\W?` - an optional non-word char
- `$` - end of string.